# Why do I have so many unnecessary packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, deb

I was installing Prey through a `.deb` file donwloaded from the official website when, all of a sudden I realized that I have so many "unnecessary" installed packages in my Ubunu laptop.

This has been my sequence of actions:

1. Tried to `sudo dpkg -i prey.deb`. Didn't work because of missing packets/conflicts:

   ```
   prey:i386 depèn de sudo.
   prey:i386 depèn de python.
   prey:i386 depèn de python-gtk2.
   prey:i386 depèn de scrot.
   prey:i386 depèn de streamer.
   prey:i386 depèn de mpg123.
   prey:i386 depèn de dmidecode.
   prey:i386 depèn de gksu.
   ```
2. I then did a `sudo apt-get update` (all good) and a `sudo apt-get upgrade` (failed because previous package installation was unsuccessful, I think). APT suggested to do an `apt-get -f install` so I did. All of a sudden I realized I have an incredibly long list of unnecessary packages that I did NOT have (yesterday, at least):

   ```
    aglfn asymptote asymptote-doc checkbox-ng checkbox-ng-service cm-super cm-super-minimal context context-modules fonts-cabin fonts-comfortaa fonts-dejavu-extra fonts-ebgaramond fonts-ebgaramond-extra
    fonts-font-awesome fonts-freefont-otf fonts-gfs-artemisia fonts-gfs-baskerville fonts-gfs-bodoni-classic fonts-gfs-complutum fonts-gfs-didot fonts-gfs-didot-classic fonts-gfs-gazis
    fonts-gfs-neohellenic fonts-gfs-olga fonts-gfs-porson fonts-gfs-solomos fonts-gfs-theokritos fonts-hosny-amiri fonts-inconsolata fonts-junicode fonts-lato fonts-linuxlibertine fonts-lobster
    fonts-lobstertwo fonts-oflb-asana-math fonts-roboto fonts-sil-gentium fonts-sil-gentium-basic fonts-sil-gentiumplus fonts-stix freeglut3 giblib1:i386 gstreamer0.10-alsa gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
    gstreamer0.10-x lcdf-typetools libasound2:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libaudit1:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcomerr2:i386
    libcups2:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libdb5.3:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 libdv4:i386 libffi6:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libftgl2 libgconf-2-4:i386 libgcrypt20:i386
    libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgif4:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnome-keyring0:i386 libgnutls-deb0-28:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgpm2:i386 libgraphite2-3:i386 libgsl0ldbl libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
    libgtk2.0-0:i386 libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhogweed4:i386 libid3tag0:i386 libimlib2:i386 libintl-perl libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-3:i386
    libkrb5support0:i386 libltdl7:i386 liblzma5:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libncursesw5:i386 libnettle6:i386 libosmesa6 libp11-kit0:i386 libpam-modules:i386 libpam0g:i386 libpango-1.0-0:i386
    libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libpoppler-qt5-1 libprojectm2v5 libpython-stdlib:i386 libpython2.7-minimal:i386
    libpython2.7-stdlib:i386 libpython3.5-minimal libpython3.5-stdlib libqca2-plugins libqca2v5 libqt5script5 libqxt-core0 libqxt-gui0 libreadline6:i386 libselinux1:i386 libsigsegv2 libsqlite3-0:i386
    libssl1.0.0:i386 libstartup-notification0:i386 libsystemd0:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtext-unidecode-perl libthai0:i386 libtiff5:i386 libtinfo5:i386 libv4l-0:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386
    libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-util1:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxml-libxml-perl
    libxml-namespacesupport-perl libxml-sax-base-perl libxml-sax-expat-perl libxml-sax-perl libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 linux-image-4.2.0-16-generic linux-image-4.2.0-18-generic
    linux-image-4.2.0-19-generic linux-image-4.2.0-22-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-16-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-18-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-19-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-22-generic
    linux-signed-image-4.2.0-18-generic linux-signed-image-4.2.0-19-generic linux-signed-image-4.2.0-22-generic m-tx mpg123:i386 musixtex pfb2t1c2pfb plainbox-secure-policy pmx python3-checkbox-ng
    python3-checkbox-support python3-jinja2 python3-plainbox python3-pyparsing python3-xlsxwriter python3.5 python3.5-minimal qml-module-qtquick-localstorage qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin scrot:i386
    streamer:i386 sudo:i386 tex4ht tex4ht-common texinfo texlive-fonts-extra texlive-fonts-extra-doc texlive-formats-extra texlive-games texlive-generic-extra texlive-humanities texlive-humanities-doc
    texlive-lang-african texlive-lang-arabic texlive-lang-cyrillic texlive-lang-czechslovak texlive-lang-english texlive-lang-european texlive-lang-french texlive-lang-german texlive-lang-greek
    texlive-lang-indic texlive-lang-italian texlive-lang-polish texlive-lang-portuguese texlive-lang-spanish texlive-luatex texlive-math-extra texlive-music texlive-omega texlive-plain-extra
    texlive-publishers texlive-publishers-doc texlive-science-doc texlive-xetex ttf-adf-accanthis ttf-adf-gillius ttf-adf-universalis ttf-dejavu-core xawtv-plugins:i386 zlib1g:i386
   ```

   Note that apart from this long list, `apt` also said that the following packages would be removed (**`sudo`**??):

   ```
    Es SUPRIMIRAN els paquets següents:
        plainbox-provider-resource-generic prey:i386 sudo
   ```

   So because of all that, I aborted `apt-get -f install`, just in case...
3. Because I wasn't sure about the `dpkg` process, I undid the first command by executing `dpkg --purge prey`.
4. At this point, I checked the list of unnecessary packages (`apt-get -f install`) again and it was reduced, but still long enough to make me cancel this command. This is the list of packages that `apt` "wants" to uninstall because they are not necessary:

   ```
   aglfn asymptote asymptote-doc checkbox-ng checkbox-ng-service cm-super cm-super-minimal context context-modules fonts-cabin fonts-comfortaa fonts-dejavu-extra fonts-ebgaramond fonts-ebgaramond-extra
   fonts-font-awesome fonts-freefont-otf fonts-gfs-artemisia fonts-gfs-baskerville fonts-gfs-bodoni-classic fonts-gfs-complutum fonts-gfs-didot fonts-gfs-didot-classic fonts-gfs-gazis
   fonts-gfs-neohellenic fonts-gfs-olga fonts-gfs-porson fonts-gfs-solomos fonts-gfs-theokritos fonts-hosny-amiri fonts-inconsolata fonts-junicode fonts-lato fonts-linuxlibertine fonts-lobster
   fonts-lobstertwo fonts-oflb-asana-math fonts-roboto fonts-sil-gentium fonts-sil-gentium-basic fonts-sil-gentiumplus fonts-stix freeglut3 gstreamer0.10-alsa gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-x
   lcdf-typetools libftgl2 libgsl0ldbl libintl-perl libosmesa6 libpoppler-qt5-1 libprojectm2v5 libpython3.5-minimal libpython3.5-stdlib libqca2-plugins libqca2v5 libqt5script5 libqxt-core0 libqxt-gui0
   libsigsegv2 libtext-unidecode-perl libxml-libxml-perl libxml-namespacesupport-perl libxml-sax-base-perl libxml-sax-expat-perl libxml-sax-perl linux-image-4.2.0-16-generic linux-image-4.2.0-18-generic
   linux-image-4.2.0-19-generic linux-image-4.2.0-22-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-16-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-18-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-19-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-22-generic
   linux-signed-image-4.2.0-18-generic linux-signed-image-4.2.0-19-generic linux-signed-image-4.2.0-22-generic m-tx musixtex pfb2t1c2pfb plainbox-provider-resource-generic plainbox-secure-policy pmx
   python3-checkbox-ng python3-checkbox-support python3-jinja2 python3-plainbox python3-pyparsing python3-xlsxwriter python3.5 python3.5-minimal qml-module-qtquick-localstorage
   qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin tex4ht tex4ht-common texinfo texlive-fonts-extra texlive-fonts-extra-doc texlive-formats-extra texlive-games texlive-generic-extra texlive-humanities
   texlive-humanities-doc texlive-lang-african texlive-lang-arabic texlive-lang-cyrillic texlive-lang-czechslovak texlive-lang-english texlive-lang-european texlive-lang-french texlive-lang-german
   texlive-lang-greek texlive-lang-indic texlive-lang-italian texlive-lang-polish texlive-lang-portuguese texlive-lang-spanish texlive-luatex texlive-math-extra texlive-music texlive-omega
   texlive-plain-extra texlive-publishers texlive-publishers-doc texlive-science-doc texlive-xetex ttf-adf-accanthis ttf-adf-gillius ttf-adf-universalis ttf-dejavu-core
   ```

I recall having this list populated with some `linux-signed-image...` and others yesterday, but definitely didn't have all of them. In fact, some if these packages I know for sure that are being used (e.g. `texlive-*`, `fonts-*`, `ttf-*`, `python-*`...) What might I have broken and how could I revert this?

I suspect the error comes from step 3 but I'm not certain about it.

**UPDATE:** Before even tinkering around with `debfoster` as suggested in the comments, I have checked some packages and I have noticed that:

- `ubuntu-desktop` is not installed (?!) -- and I'm NOT using KDE nor XCFE.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, the fact that the package lists specify `:i386` in various places indicates that Carles is already running `amd64`...

Comment: Carles, I would try `debfoster` to clean up the cruft, however it does assumes you know minimally what you are doing. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=24403

Comment: Hahaha, that was funny, I'll set up my language locale in English instead of Catalan (!). As for my situation, any other idea? I'll try `debfoster` bu t I wonder why would I have so many `*:386` entries in the first list?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro `debfoster` [has been deprecated](http://www.fruit.je/debfoster/) more than ten years ago.

Comment: @marco I do fully agree with you, however it is damn useful. If you are able to point out a competent alternative, I would be more than happy to know it. I do use aptitude purge, and Debian 8 still has a debfoster package.

Comment: There's an older thread in AskUbuntu with the same problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/722090/unable-to-install-prey-on-ubuntu15-10/722100#722100
My problem was probably caused by the 32-bit version. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few routines, old wives' tales, for finding and then cleaning out unnecessary packages, in additon to the already suggested debfoster.

### (first) but, *why* is that package installed?

A tool you will want to use while cleaning out packages is `aptitude why pkg-name`  From the aptitude man page:

```
$ aptitude why kdepim
  i   nautilus-data Recommends nautilus
  i A nautilus      Recommends desktop-base (>= 0.2)
  i A desktop-base  Suggests   gnome | kde | xfce4 | wmaker
  p   kde           Depends    kdepim (>= 4:3.4.3)
```

This only prints out the strongest dependency chain, but will answer many questions quickly. There is also `why-not` which is not so relevant to removing packages.

### package removed, config files remaining

You can find packages that are no longer used by yourself but that still have configuration files and the like remaining. To do this,  open a terminal and type

```
dpkg-query -l '*' | grep ^rc | awk '{print $2}' |xargs > my_ apt_rc_removeList.lst
```

The list generated is of all the files in the 'rc' state - removed but configuration files remaining. These left over files you will now remove, but first look over the files listed in the my_ apt_rc_removeList.lst file, to check that you do want all of this cruft removed.  Now type

```
aptitude purge `cat apt_rc_removeList.lst`
```

and all this cruft will be removed.

### gtkorphan

Another application you can use to find left over packages is
gtkorphan. From gtkorphan's description in the apt system:

> GtkOrphan is
>   a graphical tool which scans your Debian system, looking for orphaned
>   libraries. It implements a GUI front-end to deborphan, but adds the
>   package removal capability. A detailed documentation on the program
>   can be found at: http://www.marzocca.net/linux/gtkorphan.html.

You can use this to help clean out packages in other sections (other than 'libs') too.

### mark uninteresting packages as dependencies: remove asap

In aptitude, in one sub-category of your "Installed Packages", type `l` (the letter 'el') and then in the box that appears enter `?not(?automatic)` . This will now show only packages that are not dependencies of other packages. Now,scroll over each of these, and on very package that does not interest you directly, hit the `M` key. This will not remove any packages, but mark each package as "only here because, and while, something depends on it"

Now go through the sections one by one. Most of the 'only as a dependencies' packages will be in the libs section.

### mark all packages matching 'pattern' as 'auto': remove asap

All of the '-dev' packages can be marked for removal-if-not-required by

```
 aptitude markauto ~i~n"\-dev$"
```

### clean out an entire category

An entire category ("CATEGORY_NAME") can be cleaned out with

```
aptitude purge '~sCATEGORY_NAME ! ~exceptThisApp
```

Comment: `aptitude why <pktname>` was enough to discover that the following (previously installed) packages had been somehow removed or where in wrong states: `texlive-full`, `ubuntu-desktop`, `gstreamer0.1 ...`. I have repaired them (with `dpkg-reconfigure <pktname>` or `apt-get --reinstall install <pktname>`) and the list has shrunk to a reasonable number of unused packets.

Comment: I would be curious to know how many `aptitude why` commands circle bacj to say `because aptitude`. Also, show us your boobs.